# How to Read a Simple Json Result (from Google calculator) in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a json result from the next google Query:

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?MXN

The result is this:

```
{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "13.3317335 Mexican pesos",error: "",icc: true}
```

So i'm just trying to decode with this:

```
import json, urllib2

j=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?MXN")
print json.load(j)
```

But i'm having this error (Traceback):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafael/gitSources/PythonConcept/Monpy/negApi.py", line 4, in <module>
    print json.load(j)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, I just read many tutorials  :/

Thanks :)!

Comment: JSON vould be `{"lhs": "1 U.S. dollar","rhs": "13.3317335 Mexican pesos","error": "","icc": true}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not JSON but you can still parse it yourself - like this:

```
import ast

resp = '{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "13.3317335 Mexican pesos",error: "",icc: true}'

d = {}
for pair in resp[1:-1].split(','):
    (k,v) = pair.split(':')
    v = v.strip()
    if v == "true":
        v = "True"
    try:
        v = ast.literal_eval(v)
    except:
        print "Couldn't eval " + v
    d[k] = v

print d
```

You could also fix up the formatting to be json and then use the json parser like this:

```
import json

resp = '{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "13.3317335 Mexican pesos",error: "",icc: true}'

s = "{"    
for pair in resp[1:-1].split(','):
    (k,v) = pair.split(':')
    s += '"%s" : %s,' % (k,v)
s = s[:-1] + "}"

print json.loads(s)
```

Comment: wow that's great.. but i want to know what is happening here please :)

Comment: for example, in the for sintax, you are going from 1 to -1?

Comment: string[1:-1] means the whole string except first and last character, then split along commas, then split along colons

Comment: thanks !! :) one last question, what is (k,v)? ? that is a dictionary?, I'm starting to develop in python and there are so many terms that I don't understand

Comment: (k,v) is a tuple .... and you can assign list to a tuple so `(a,b) = L` is short-hand for `a=L[0], b=L[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rate-exchange.appspot.com`, which uses the Google API but returns valid json:

```
http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=MXN&q=1
{"to": "MXN", "rate": 12.7523369, "from": "USD", "v": 12.7523369}
```

Here's how to use it with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=MXN&q=1')
>>> r.json['v']
12.7523369
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

import re

```
s = '{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "13.3317335 Mexican pesos",error: "",icc: true}'
only_numbers=re.sub(r'[^0-9,.]+', '', s)
m = re.match(r"(\d+..),(\d+.\d+),,", only_numbers)
currency=m.group(2)
```

output: 13.3317335